# Ajax Form do not work after after update to Windows 10

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-10, ajaxform

I have problem with my web application.
Project was created in MVC 4. Few days ago I updated my operating system to Windows 10. After that in all views where I use ajax form, it posts model as null so I got NullReferenceException in controllers. Before update everything worked perfectly. Standard post actions using classic form works correctly. Also ajax requests used via jQuery works. I am totally stuck.

Anybody had some idea how to fix it?

**EDIT**

I created empty mvc application for test and prepare simple ajax form and it works.. Still do not know what is reason for given below example.
All needed scripts are provided for Layout view (jquery, ajax etc).

Below is only one component of whole view. It is too big to post it here.
It worked perfectly and after I updated windows it stop working (maybe I did somthing else but I cannot revert to state before).

Model

```
public class UniversityModel
{
    public UniversityDto UniversityDto { get; set; }

    public IList<UniversityDto> UniversityDtos { get; set; }

    public UniversityModel()
    {
        UniversityDtos = new List<UniversityDto>();
    }
}

public class UniversityDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LongName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AddUniversity([Bind(Prefix = "UniversityDto")]UniversityDto model)
    {
        UniversityModel universityModel = new UniversityModel();
        using (ISession session = (ISession)_unitOfWork.GetBaseSession())
        {
            using (Infrastructure.Data.Interfaces.ITransaction transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    model.ShortName = model.ShortName.Trim();
                    model.LongName = model.LongName.Trim();
                    var entity = Mapper.Map<University>(model);
                    session.Save(entity);
                    transaction.Commit();

                    universityModel = CompleteUniversityModel(session);
                    return PartialView("UniversityPartial", universityModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    universityModel = CompleteUniversityModel(session, model);
                    return PartialView("UniversityPartial", universityModel);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

View (I omitted script section and master view)

```
@model ThesisNavigator.Presentation.WebFrontend.Models.StructureController.UniversityModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddUniversity", "Structure", new AjaxOptions()
{
HttpMethod = "POST",
UpdateTargetId = "UniversityPartialContainer",
LoadingElementId = "loadingUniversity",
OnBegin = "onBeginAddUniversity",
OnSuccess = "onSuccessAddUniversity",
OnFailure = "onFailureAddUniversity"
},
new { @class = "form-inline", @id = "formAddUniversity" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UniversityDto.ShortName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UniversityDto.ShortName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UniversityDto.LongName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UniversityDto.LongName, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Dodaj</button>
<div class="center">
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @id = "formAddUniversityValidationSummary", @class = "center", @style = "display:none" })
</div>
}
<div id="universityList">
@{ Html.RenderPartial("UniversityListPartial", Model.UniversityDtos); }
</div>
```

Comment: Post some code to get some good quality answers